# Jquery form validation: Add error message in the custom validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Is it possible to add an error message for an element in a custom validation function?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#">
    <div id="appDiv">
        <input name="nEle" type="hidden" value="validate" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input name="nEle1" />
    <br/>
    <input name="nEle2" />
    <br/>
    <input name="nEle3" />
    <br/>
    <input name="nEle4" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
(function (window, $) {
    function Plugin(ele, params) {
        return this;
    };
    Plugin.prototype = {
        isValid: function () {
            /* After some validation, suppose this raises error and returns false */
            return false;
        },
        getErrors: function () {
            /* The validation logic in "isValid" stores the error in the plugin context and this function gets the errors form it and returns */
            return "Error evaluated in plugin after its own validation.";
        }
    }
    $.fn.plugin = function (params) {
        var retval = this,
            initlist = this;
        initlist.each(function () {
            var p = $(this).data("plugindata");
            if (!p) {
                $(this).data('plugindata', new Plugin(this, params));
            } else {
                if (typeof params === 'string' && typeof p[params] === 'function') {
                    retval = p[params]();
                    initlist = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return retval || initlist;
    };
})(window, jQuery);

$.validator.addMethod("customValidation", function (value, element, jqPlugin) {
    if (!jqPlugin.plugin('isValid')) {
        var errorString = jqPlugin.plugin('getErrors');
        console.log("Error String : %s", errorString);
        alert("How to set this as error : " + errorString);
        /* How to display the error informaiton which is in the errorString ? */
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Default custom validation message.");

$(document).ready(function () {
    var jqPlugin = $('#appDiv').plugin();
    $('form').validate({
        ignore: [],
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        rules: {
            nEle: {
                required: true,
                customValidation: jqPlugin
            },
            nEle1: {
                required: true,
            },
            nEle2: {
                required: true,
            },
            nEle3: {
                required: true,
            },
            nEle4: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            nEle: {
                customValidation: "Fix error with custom validation."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("Validaton Success..!!");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**JQuery** - A probable fix, only deltas :

```
$.validator.addMethod("customValidation", function (value, element, jqPlugin) {
    if (!jqPlugin.plugin('isValid')) {
        var errorString = jqPlugin.plugin('getErrors');
        console.log("Error String : %s", errorString);
        alert("How to set this as error : " + errorString);
        /* How to display the error informaiton which is in the errorString ? */
        this.errorList.push({
            message: errorString,
            element: element
        });
        this.errorMap[$(element).attr('name')] = status.error;
        //        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Default custom validation message.");
```

**CSS :**

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/m8eEs - Original Code

http://jsfiddle.net/m8eEs/1/ - Updated for clarity

http://jsfiddle.net/m8eEs/2/ - A probable fix which I'm still not happy with, not sure if this is the only way to do it..!!

In the above, I would like to add error message in the function "customValidation" for the element "nEle".

**Edited**: Maybe its better to add the reason for this kind of question. (directly copied from the comments below)

I know that. But I need to add the error message inside the function. The reason is, element creation & validation(application specific validation, not only the supported required/number/range..) logic is done in a separate plugin(say 'X'). And a set of APIs is exposed to get the validation status and the errors if any. But this element is grouped along with other elements that are validated through the 'validation' plugin. So, in a nutshell, the "customValidation" function just calls the APIs from the 'X' plugin and get the validation status & error messages if any, but stuck with showing it.

Comment: See the part in the custom method that says `"Default custom validation message."`… <<-- that's the piece that would get replaced with your custom error message.  Otherwise, I have no idea what you're asking.  You have no function in your custom method nor have you explained what this mystery method is supposed to do.

Comment: I know that. But I need to add the error message inside the function. The reason is, element creation & validation(application specific validation, not only the supported required/number/range..) logic is done in a separate plugin(say 'X'). And a set of APIs are exposed to get the validation status and the errors if any. But this element is grouped along with other elements that are validated through the 'validation' plugin. So, in a nutshell the "customValidation" function just calls the APIs from the 'X' plugin and get the validation status & error messages if any, but stuck with showing it.

Comment: `addMethod` contains two things, a function and an error message.  If the function returns `true`, the element passes validation and no message is displayed.  If the function returns `false`, the element fails validation and the message is displayed.  That's it.

Comment: The only way to dynamically change an error message after the plugin has been initialized is by using the `.rules('add')` method, which unfortunately, you cannot put inside of `addMethod()`.  Without showing us an example of what you're trying to do, we cannot make intelligent answers.

Comment: Check the code now, a bit more clarity is added on the use case. A probable fix/hack is also shown, but I was not happy with it. So I posted this question to check if there is an other way of doing it. Also, I'm in no position to change the divisions plugin code, and it actually validates the structure of the division and not the input element itself. Input element is added for the sake of the validator plugin. Also the division come in sequence with the other input elements, which can easily be validated using the validator plugin.